NGRX How to change the store without changing the refference, so it shouldnt trigger custom selector method
Have a entity collection and subscribed in the component.entity collection will be updating frequently by websocket message. In the component item on the list can be selected by check box.Whenever store updates the selection on the component got removed. Selectoin of item in row not persisting in the view. Also I am using a custom selector method having filter, sorting of the list     and this selector projection method using 3 parameters ie, list , filtercriteria,sort criteria. So If I update the item as selected in  store , this custom selector method getting triggering and all the filter , sort functionality triigering again.  How to avoid the this un necessary computation
Selection of item in the list stored in the component store and whenever the store updates , it will compare with component state and merged the changes from store

Please share some code. :-)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
